# Get all custom post types excepted some...

Tags: posts, query

I stack since a few hours now and I'm sure that this is not so complicated. 
I would like to get all custom post types into this

```
$posts = query_posts( $query_string.'post_type=POST-TYPE1,POST-TYPE2,POST-TYPE3&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=-1&' );
```

I know that there is this function: `$post_types=get_post_types('','names');`
And I have some Post Types which I want to exclude. E.g. "Portfolio".

So how is it possible to get the `$posts` looking for all important Types?!

Thanks a lot !!

Philipp

Comment: How do you distinguish between "important" and non(?) important posts?

Comment: Well, I mean all my custom Post Types inclusive "posts" and "pages" exclusive "attachements" and "portfolio".

Answer (score 3):

Following code generates the array to use as argument.

```
<?php
// Excluded CPTs. You can expand the list.
$exclude_cpts = array(
    'portfolio'
);
// Builtin types needed.
$builtin = array(
    'post',
    'page',
    'attachment'
);
// All CPTs.
$cpts = get_post_types( array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
) );
// remove Excluded CPTs from All CPTs.
foreach($exclude_cpts as $exclude_cpt)
    unset($cpts[$exclude_cpt]);
// Merge Builtin types and 'important' CPTs to resulting array to use as argument.
$post_types = array_merge($builtin, $cpts);
```

My suggestion is to use `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts`. See [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Thanks a lot Max! I'm so sorry but I don't get the results. Even if I try to use `echo $post_types`. Then I should get an list of the types, right?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the code. Fixed. First of all, you MUST use `DEBUG` when developing! That's why you don't see any errors. Second, don't `echo` an array, `print_r()` it.

Comment: I've meant `WP_DEBUG`.

Comment: Thank you, Max! The Debug-Mode didn't help because I've not been able to load anything. ;) But now I get an result:
`Array ( [0] => post [1] => page [n-finalist] => n-finalist [event] => event [ancient] => ancient [w-finalist] => w-finalist [c-pages] => c-pages [n-page] => n-page [w-page] => w-page [worldtour] => worldtour [about] => about ) Array`

That's great. But now I need a comma separated list. I didn't find something about how to get just everything from [xxx] in `print_r;`

Comment: See PHP docs for `explode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's a `wp_filter_object_list()` call specifying `names` as output and `and` as operator. As you can't distinguish between `portfolio` and the rest by it's objects data, you'll have to do unset that one manually.

```
$cpts = get_post_types( array(
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false
) );
unset( $cpts['portfolio'] );
foreach ( $cpts as $cpt )
    $r[] = get_post_type_object( $cpt );

printf(
     '<pre>%s</pre><br /><pre>%s</pre>'
     // The names only
    ,var_export( $cpts, true )
     // The full post type objects
    ,var_export( $r, true )
);
```